# Recorrer listas JAVA

Tags: java

este es el primer ejercicio con listas y todavía no me aclaro con como hacerlo... Pongo el enunciado y lo que llevo haciendo con el código, muchas gracias y un saludo.

1. Método getImporte.

Este método devolverá el importe total del ticket.

Para ello tendrás que recorrer la lista completa de compras realizadas y calcular la suma acumulada de todas ellas.

2. Método getNumArticulos.

En este caso se devolverá la cantidad total de artículos comprados. Ten en cuenta que si se adquieren, por ejemplo, tres ejemplares de un determinado producto y dos de otro, el total de artículos adquiridos sería cinco, no dos.

Para ello primero tenemos la clase Compra con estos atributos:

```
public Compra (String producto, double precio, int unidades) {
    this.producto = producto;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.unidades = unidades;
}


// --------------------------------------------------
//                    GETTERS
// --------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Obtiene el nombre del producto.
 * @return nombre del producto
 */
public String getProducto() {
    return this.producto;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el precio del producto.
 * @return precio del producto
 */
public double getPrecio() {
    return this.precio;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el número de unidades compradas del producto.
 * @return número de unidades compradas del producto
 */
public int getUnidades() {
    return this.unidades;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el importe total de la compra. Se calcula multiplicando el precio 
 * del producto por el número de unidades adquiridas.
 * @return importe total de la compra
 */
public double getImporte () {
    return this.unidades * this.precio;
}
```

Y aqui tenemos la clase ticket compra

```
 **
 * Representa el ticket de la compra realizada por un cliente.
 * Contiene información sobre fecha y hora, así como el vendedor, los productos adquiridos, 
 * cantidades, precios, etc.
 * El registro de los productos comprados, junto con la cantidad y el precio se almacenan en forma de lista 
 * de objetos <code>Compra</code>, es decir, una lista de ternas <code>(producto, precio, unidades)</code>.
 * @author profe + nombre alumno/a
 */
public class TicketCompra {
    private static final  DateTimeFormatter FORMATO_FECHA_HORA = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    private final String vendedor;
    private final LocalDateTime instante;
    private final List<Compra> listaCompra;


    // --------------------------------------------------
    //               CONSTRUCTORES
    // --------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Constructor para instanciar un ticket a partir de un vendedor, un instante (timestamp)
     * y una lista de objetos Compra.
     * Si la lista pasada es <code>null</code>, se creará una lista vacía.
     * @param vendedor vendedor que atendió en la compra
     * @param instante momento de la compra (fecha y hora)
     * @param listaCompra lista de la compra. Lista de objetos Compra, ternas del tipo (producto, precio, unidades)
     */
    public TicketCompra (String vendedor, LocalDateTime instante, List<Compra> listaCompra) {
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
        this.instante = instante;
        if (listaCompra != null) {
            this.listaCompra = listaCompra;
        } else {
            this.listaCompra = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor para instanciar un ticket a partir de un vendedor y un instante (timestamp).
     * Inicialmente la lista de objetos compra estará vacía.
     * @param vendedor vendedor que atendió en la compra
     * @param instante momento de la compra (fecha y hora)
     */
    public TicketCompra (String vendedor, LocalDateTime instante) {
        this (vendedor, instante, null);
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor para instanciar un ticket a partir de un vendedor y una lista de compras.
     * El momento de la compra se considerará el actual.
     * @param vendedor vendedor que atendió en la compra
     * @param listaCompra lista de la compra. Lista de objetos Compra, ternas del tipo (producto, precio, unidades)
     */
    public TicketCompra (String vendedor, List<Compra> listaCompra) {
        this (vendedor, LocalDateTime.now(), listaCompra);
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor para instanciar un ticket a partir de un vendedor.
     * El momento de la compra se considerará el actual.
     * Inicialmente la lista de objetos compra estará vacía.
     * @param vendedor vendedor que atendió en la compra
     */
    public TicketCompra (String vendedor) {
        this (vendedor, LocalDateTime.now());
    }
    
    
    // --------------------------------------------------
    //                    GETTERS
    // --------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Obtiene el vendedor que atendió en la compra
     * @return vendedor que atendió en la compra
     */
    public String getVendedor() {
        return this.vendedor;
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene el instante (<code>timestamp</code> o fecha y hora) en el que se realizó la compra.
     * @return instante de la compra
     */
    public LocalDateTime getInstante() {
        return instante;
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene la lista completa de los objetos <code>Compra</code> del ticket.
     * @return lista de objetos <code>Compra</code>
     */
    public List<Compra> getListaCompra() {
        return listaCompra;
    }
    

    // --------------------------------------------------
    //                   TOSTRING
    // --------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Representación textual de un ticket de compra.
     * Tendrá el formato {vendedor, instante, numArticulos, importe, [lista de tickets]}.
     * @return representación textual del ticket.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format ("{%s, %s, %d, %6.2f, %s}", 
                this.vendedor, 
                this.instante.format(FORMATO_FECHA_HORA), 
                this.getNumArticulos(),
                this.getImporte(),
                this.listaCompra);
    }
    
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // MÉTODOS QUE DEBEN SER IMPLEMETADOS POR EL ALUMNADO
    // --------------------------------------------------
    
    // Ejercicio 1.1
    // -------------
    /**
     * Devuelve el importe total de la compra. Tiene en cuenta todos los productos
     * comprados, su cantidad y su precio.
     * @return importe total de la compra
     */
    public double getImporte() {
        return 0.0; // Sustituir este return por el código que resuelve el ejercicio




    }

    // Ejercicio 1.2
    // -------------
    /**
     * Devuelve el total de artículos adquiridos en la compra. Tiene en cuenta la cantidad de 
     * cada uno de los productos comprados.
     * @return importe total de la compra
     */
    public int getNumArticulos() {
        return 0; // Sustituir este return por el código que resuelve el ejercicio




    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Matuto, para **getImporte** (yo le cambiaría el nombre por **getMontoTotal**), solo tienes que iterar sobre **listaCompra**, a cada compra le pides el importe (getImporte()), y los vas sumando, para **getNumArticulos** (getCantArticulos?), solo tienes que devolver el tamaño de la lista, osea, **listaCompra.size()**.

Comment: @MarcePuente es que el ejercicio nos lo piden asi... y como los itero para poder pedirlos? Es el primer ejercicio que hago con listas y no los comprendo...

Comment: `acumulador += compra.getPrecio()`. Piensalo un poco. Aquí no enseñamos a programar. Ese es el trabajo de un profesor y de material educativo.

Comment: @Mateo pero la duda es en que parte del código lo pongo

Comment: En la función donde quieres calcular el precio total `getImporte`. Tienes que sumar el precio de cada producto de la lista. Piensalo un poco antes de seguir extendiendo la conversación en los comentarios.

Comment: @Mateo me dice que no está la variable.

Comment: @Mateo public double getImporte() {
        
       double importe = 0;
        double i;
        
        for ( i = 0; i < listaCompra.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listaCompra.get((int) i));
            importe += producto.getPrecio();}
        
        
        
        return i;
    }

Comment: Intenta la *sentencia for mejorada*: `for( Compra com : this.listaCompra ){ // Aqui puedes usar: com.unidades`.

Comment: @Sal como quedaria? me da error al hacerlo asi

Comment: @Sal el com.unidades donde se pondría luego? Para sumarlos frente al iterador

Comment: @Mateo porfavor ayúdame que es la 1era parte del ejercicio que son 7

Answer (score 1):

Así es como lo he hecho. Muchas gracias y un saludo

```
public double getImporte() {           
            
    double importe = 0;
    for (Compra com : this.listaCompra){ 
        importe += com.getPrecio();
    }
    return importe;
}
```

Comment: Me alegra que hayas llegado a la solución por tu cuenta.

Comment: Muy bien, si quieres hacerlo con el for "común", le pides a la lista la compra y a la compra el importe: ***importe += listaCompra.get( i ).getImporte();***.