# iterar sobre una lista

Tags: java

no se como poder iterar sobre una lista para que me de una suma. El enunciado es:

Este método devolverá el importe total del ticket.

Para ello tendrás que recorrer la lista completa de compras realizadas y calcular la suma acumulada de todas ellas.

public double getImporte() {

```
    double i;
    
    for ( i = 0; i < listaCompra.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(listaCompra.get((int) i));
    }
    
    
    return i;
}
```

Me recorre el largo, pero no me recorre la suma de los precios

Comment: pero.. ahi la estas iterando.. cada item, en cada vuelta, es tu variable precio.. entonces... que sigue?

Comment: Buenas @gbianchi https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589205/recorrer-listas-java?noredirect=1#comment1041831_589205 este es el post donde sale todo. Muchas gracias y un saludo. Tiene que salir de la lista de otra clase sumar el precio, cantidad

Comment: Vamos. No es tan difícil. Necesitas una variable que lleve la cuenta y sumarle los precios de todos los artículos.

Comment: sigo sin entender cual es el problema.. tu pregunta es como recorrerla, y aca la estas recorriendo...

Comment: Y no repitas tu pregunta!! actualiza la original, a esta le falta un monton de contexto...

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que el título de la pregunta es diferente a lo que en realidad pregunta.

Comment: el problema es que me suma el size no los datos de precio del interior

Comment: @gbianchi ya la he actualizado con el código que he. hecho

Comment: Eso es porque estás sumando `i` que va de 0 hasta `size`.

Comment: @Mateo entonces hasta donde tengo que sumarla?

Comment: No esta sumando nada en ningun lado, esta devolviendo el iterador!!!! donde estas sumando los precios???? lee tu codigo.. entendelo...

Comment: No, la pregunta no es hasta dónde. Sino qué. Tienes que sumar los precios. La variable `i` solo la usas para acceder a los precios de la lista.

Comment: donde estas sumando algo??? donde hay un mas que sume un valor a una varialbe? y lo guarde en una variable? en que parte de este codigo esta?

Comment: ahora es cuando estoy mas liado jajaja @gbianchi

Comment: vos queres sumar algo, no??? como se hace una suma, en cualquier lenguaje????

Comment: lo siento por ser novato, trato de aprender. Es un grado superior a distancia y la posibilidad de solucionar dudas son escasas

Comment: Claro... pero esta pregunta es mas que basica.. como se suman 2 variables en java?

Comment: @gbianchi creo que sí sabe **cómo** sumar. Pero no sabe **qué** tiene que sumar.

Comment: @gbianchi importe += i; pero donde lo pongo? en que parte

Comment: no.. eso le esta sumando i a importe.. vos queres sumarle importa a la variable que itera???

Comment: @matuto estás sumando **bien** las cosas **equivocadas**. [Te dejé una pista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589205/recorrer-listas-java?noredirect=1#comment1041869_589205)

Comment: no, lo que quiero sumar es el precio

Comment: @Mateo me dice que la clase producto no está creada

Comment: @gbianchi         for ( i = 0; i < listaCompra.size(); i++) { 
            System.out.println(listaCompra.get((int) i));
            importe += Compra.getPrecio();}

Comment: @gbianchi pero me da error porque dice que getPrecio no es una variable estática

Comment: Creo que lo que estas refiriendo es mas que una pregunta.. necesitas todo un concepto.. si no podes diferenciar entre clases estaticas y no estaticas debes leer sobre eso. aca no hay un error en si... hay falta de concepto.. y requieren explicaciones mas profundas que las que podemos darte en una respuesta...